# Rails I18n works in console but not in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I try to use internationalization in a rails project but it doesn't work like it should in the views. Surprisingly it works in the console.
These are my locale files:

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  home:
    index:
      bla: "Hello"
```

config/locales/de.yml

```
de:
  home:
    index:
      bla: "Hallo"
```

My application_controller looks like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale
  ...

private
  ...

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_tld || I18n.default_locale
  end 

  def extract_locale_from_tld
    parsed_locale = request.host.split('.').last
    I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(parsed_locale) ? parsed_locale : nil 
  end
end
```

In the rails console i get

```
> I18n.available_locales  
=> [:en, :de] 
> I18n.t 'home.index.bla'
=> "Hello"
> I18n.locale = 'de'
=> "de"
> I18n.t 'home.index.bla'
=> "Hallo"
```

When I open myurl.com in the browser everything is fine and the correct translation "Hello" is rendered. But when I go to myurl.de I can only see the key "bla" instead of "Hallo". The generated html is:

```
<span title="translation missing: de.home.index.bla" class="translation_missing">Bla</span>
```

In both cases I18n.locale is set to the correct value in the set_locale function.
What's going wrong and what should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Where's the view code that's generating the wrong HTML?  Seems pretty relevant.

Comment: Did you restart the app after creating de.yml?

Comment: Thanks, restarting solved the problem.